Database both joined and not joined to an AG
I have a Distributed Availability Group (DAG) from cluster Main to cluster Alt - both with two replicas.
The Main is the primary and Alt is a forwarder
One (of many) databases called MyDb in the AG on the forwarder side's secondary replica was in a bad state and was dropped.
I've used automatic seeding to bring back the database but it failed with a failure_state_desc = SQL Error
Now the database is stuck in RESTORING state and the error log says:

Starting up database 'MyDb'.
The database 'MyDb' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run.

When I run
ALTER DATABASE [MyDb] SET HADR AVAILABILITY GROUP = [fwdAg];  

I get an error

Msg 41145, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
Cannot join database 'MyDb' to availability group 'fwdAg'.  The database has already joined the availability group.  This is an informational message.  No user action is required.

When I try
ALTER DATABASE [MyDb] SET HADR resume;

I get error

Msg 35242, Level 16, State 16, Line 50
Cannot complete this ALTER DATABASE  SET HADR operation on database 'MyDb'. The database is not joined to an availability group. After the database has joined the availability group, retry the command.

which contradicts the previous error. I get the same error if I try
ALTER DATABASE [MyDb] SET HADR off;  

And when I query the DMVs
select
    adc.database_name as dbName
    , ag.name as agName
    , drs.synchronization_state_desc
from sys.availability_databases_cluster as adc
join sys.availability_groups as ag
    on adc.group_id = ag.group_id
left join sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS drs
    on drs.group_id = adc.group_id 
    and drs.group_database_id = adc.group_database_id
where ag.name = 'fwdAg'

I get back the agName but not the database_replica_states info.
How do I re-add the DB to the AG on the secondary (forwarder side)?
I'm on SQL Server version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)
Oct  8 2022 05:58:25
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 20348: ) (Hypervisor)

SQL Error means that seeding ran into some issue and you'll need to check the errorlogs. In terms of the state the database thinks it is in versus what the cluster/availability manager thinks is in dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states. That'd be the minimum to start investigating.
